# Can't get my myself out of rebase conflicts

Tags: git, rebase, merge-conflict-resolution

Here is the structure

Branches:
A-->B-->C

I'm trying to rebase changes to **B** & then finally to **C**. The first time I tried to do it I got a merge conflict (which I expected) going to branch B. I resolved the conflict but must have done something wrong because after I resolved it wouldn't let me do `git rebase --continue` because it told me there weren't any changes. The only thing I could find was to do a `git rebase --skip` which is fine and all but ever time i do a reverse merge i have the same conflict and have to go through it again. Can anyone give me some advice on how to get out of this endless loop?